# Mockito argument capture within method statements

Tags: unit-testing, parameters, arguments, mockito, stub

In the class under test, I have a method as below:

```
public RedirectView directToUrl()
    {
        URL url = urlUtils.createUrl( x.getPrefix(), new URLMaker( "/my/relative/url" ) );
        return new RedirectView( url.toString() );
    }
```

Note that the method itself does not have any parameter. I am trying to write a unit test that verifies the parameter value `/my/relative/url` passed in the first line of the method body. In the test, the method `urlUtils.createUrl` cannot be invoked as-is without mocking (has side-effects and depends on multiple external stuffs). In that, I figured that I cannot do argument capture in when-then statement in Mockito.

Any idea or thought will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is x in your code? Just trying to make a point that the method depends upon some other value.

If you are unit testing directToUrl() method, you can capture RedirectView and verify that it has correct value based on mocked X.

Comment: x is a class that handles the HTTP request and some of the custom stuffs built around it. The test does not have to care about this particular parameter usage. This is a reason why this `urlUtils.createUrl` needs to be stubbed out.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.   So you stub out `createUrl`.  Great.  Then in your test, you should check that the return value from `directToUrl` matches whatever URL you've made `createUrl` return.  Which part is causing you difficulty?

Comment: I want to capture the value passed to `new URLMaker( "/my/relative/url" )` instead of hard-coding that in the test.

Comment: In that case, you can create spy URLMaker and check for constructor argument. May be we can help you if you post your test code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using `Answer` or `doAnswer` in Mockito.

```
public void test_directToUrl()
    {
        final String expRelUrl = "/my/relative/URL";

        Answer<URL> url = new Answer<URL>() {
            public URL answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                URLMaker um = invocation.getArgumentAt(1, URLMaker.class);
                assertThat(um.getRelativeUrl(), equalTo(expRelUrl));
                return new URL("random_prefix" + um.getRelativeUrl());
            }
        };

        when( urlUtils.createUrl( Mockito.any(), Mockito.any() ) )
                .thenAnswer( url );
        RedirectView redirectView = directToUrl();
        assertThat(redirectView.getUrl(), containsString(expRelUrl));
    }
```

Hope it will help others too.